# Fetch User Details from Person Or Group Field Using REST API

Tags: rest, api

I was trying to retrieve user WorkPhone from a people and group field but its throwing error saying

> The query to field 'Application/WorkPhone' is not valid.

But I tried the same query for the MobilePhone and Email that's working fine.
Please guide me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Have you tried just "Phone"?

Comment: Hi that is also not working I don't understand same API is able to give me result for the MobilePhone and it's not working for WorkPhone

Comment: how about something like `https://sitecollecurl/_api/lists/getbytitle('List name')/items?$expand=Application&$select=Application/WorkPhone,Application/EMail,Application/Title` ?

Comment: sorry this also dint worked getting below error                                                                                    The query to field 'Application/WorkPhone' is not valid.

Comment: Does the value of the item contain a group? I found that I get no error if it's a person in the field, but if I put a group there, I get a 500. But I got a different error message.

Comment: The error you are mentioning is different

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this issue its an urgent and need to be addressed

Answer (score 0):

2010 or 2013 REST? On-prem or Office 365/SharePoint Online?

What was your REST URL?

Please update your question...

This works for me in SharePoint Online:

```
https://yourServer/sites/site/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='WorkPhone')?@v='i:0%23.f|membership|samc@yourDomain.com'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer                                                                           
I am trying to fetch via mentioned url https://url/_api/lists/getbytitle('List name')/items?$expand=name_x0020_Manager/ID&$select=name_x0020_Manager/WorkPhone                                                                                                        Instead of WorkPhone if i use Mobile Phone it works fine and give me result for the phone number